# How do I add an item to the front of the queue?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a Windows service that makes use of a FileSystemWatcher to monitor a particular folder for additions of a particular file type.  Due the gap between the Created event and when the file is actually ready to be manipulated, I created a `Queue<T>` to hold the file names that need processing.  In the Created event handler, the item is added to the queue.  Then using a timer, I periodically grab the first item from the queue and process it.  If the processing fails, the item is added back to the queue so the service can retry processing it later.

This works fine but I've found it has one side-effect:  the first processing attempt for new items does not happen until all the old retry items have been retried.  Since it's possible the queue could contain many items, I'd like to force the new items to the front of the queue so they are processed first.  But from the [`Queue<T>` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx), there is no obvious way of adding an item to the front of the queue.

I suppose I could create a second queue for new items and process that one preferentially but having a single queue seems simpler.

So is there an easy way to add an item to the front of the queue?

Comment: If you're adding to the front and tail of a queue, it ceases to be a queue, pedantically speaking.

Comment: why not add the retry items into their own collection to be processed later?

Comment: In the STL you would use a deque (which I've heard pronounced as "deck" but I really don't know).  It's a double-ended queue.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/ It doesn't appear that there is one in System.Collections.Generic, but you could write you own in the manner you describe.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It kind of looks like you want a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx), which allows you to do things like `AddFirst()`, `AddLast()`, `RemoveFirst()`, and `RemoveLast()`.

Comment: +1 Thats actually a great solution. Doh, why didn't I think off that!

Comment: +++ A great solution indeed.  This is what I was looking for; a queue that isn't really a queue.  :)

Comment: As an added bonus, LinkedList<T> is doubly linked, so all the operations listed above are O(1).

Comment: So what you have here is in effect two stacks. Which is fine if you don't need FIFO order.

Comment: This is the best answer as it allows you to add to the start or end and remove from either the start or end.

Comment: @JimMischel If you limit yourself to AddFirst and RemoveLast (or Vice-versa), you get FIFO

Answer (score 15):

Simply use the Peek method in your timer callback instead of Dequeue. 
If processing succeeds, then dequeue the item.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I agree with CanSpice; however, you could:

```
var items = queue.ToArray();
queue.Clear();
queue.Enqueue(newFirstItem);
foreach(var item in items)
    queue.Enqueue(item);
```

Nasty hack, but it will work ;)

Rather you might think about adding a second queue instance.  This one being the 'priority' queue that you check/execute first.  This would be a little cleaner.  You might even create your own queue class to wrap it all up nice and neat like ;)

Comment: It did occur to me to empty the queue and refill it but imagined a mechanism much uglier than what you propose.  However, a custom queue class is intriguing.

Comment: You could add an extension method to make it prettier

Answer (score 7):

Do not take from the queue until you processed it, is an alternative solution.

Use `queue.Peek()` to get your first item and only `Dequeue()` when the operation succeeds.

Use `queue.Count > 0` before you `Peek()`, else you will get the 'queue is empty' result.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using two queues:  one for new items, and one for retry items.  Wrap both queues in a single object that has the same semantics as a queue as far as removal goes, but allows you to flag things as going into the New queue or the Retry queue on insert.  Something like:

```
public class DoubleQueue<T>
{
    private Queue<T> NewItems = new Queue<T>();
    private Queue<T> RetryItems = new Queue<T>();

    public Enqueue(T item, bool isNew)
    {
        if (isNew)
            NewItems.Enqueue(item);
        else
            RetryItems.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (NewItems.Count > 0)
            return NewItems.Dequeue();
        else
            return RetryItems.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to have a `Count` property that returns the number of items in both queues.

If you have more than two types of items, then it's time to upgrade to a priority queue.

Comment: It makes no sense. Queue is queue. He should use linked list.

Comment: The problem with the linked list approach is that he really shouldn't be putting all new items at the front, despite what he's literally asking for.  He wants new items processed before items that need to be retried.  He doesn't want new items processed before older new items.  Therefore, the proper solution is two queues, and this wraps it decently.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like what you're after is a [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) - This is a LIFO (Last in, first out) buffer.

Comment: -1, He only wants certain types of items to be inserted into the beginning of the queue, not all.  Thus a Stack is just as flawed for his purpose.

Comment: @csharptest.net, I've read the OP's question thrice now, and that's not how it scans to me.  It sounds to me like the OP *always* wants new items to process before old items.

Comment: @Kirk I originally thought that too, but after re-reading it it seems he wants to have all new items take priority over old items (regardless of how long the old items have been waiting)

Answer (score 2):

You need a **Priority Queue**. Take a look at the [C5 Collections Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/). It's IntervalHeap implements the IPriorityQueue interface. The C5 collections library is pretty good, too.

I believe you can find implementations at http://www.codeproject.com and http://www.codeplex.com as well.